# insert on weka -doesn't show me the file

Tags: dataframe, data-mining, weka

I have wrote that in notepad

```
      a   b   c   d   e
1     1   1   1   0   0
2     1   1   0   1   0
3     1   0   1   0   1
4     0   1   1   1   0
```

then I save it as s.ar
I open WEKA and try to  insert it but it doesn't show me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ar` is not a file extension that Weka recognizes.

If you meant to create an ARFF file, then please see the [documentation](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/) for that file format.

Have you thought about just using CSV (comma-separated values, `.csv` extension) instead? You could rewrite your data like this:

```
ID,a,b,c,d,e
1,1,1,1,0,0
2,1,1,0,1,0
3,1,0,1,0,1
4,0,1,1,1,0
```

Then you can load it in Weka's Explorer (after selecting *CSV data files* as type from the file chooser dialog).